# How to add a year in select tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add the year 2015 to present year in a select tag in html using javascript. I have a code below but it does not display or return the expected value and the select tag is also empty. how can i achieved that?

HTML:

```
                <div class="cell colspan3">
                    <div class="input-control select full-size">
                        <h5>Year:</h5>
                        <select id="cboYear">
                           <option value="0" selected disabled hidden>Select Year</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function Years() {
    var today = new Date(),
      yyyy = today.getFullYear()


    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++, yyyy++) {
        for (var x = 1; x > i; x++) {
            $('#cboYear').append('<option value ="' + x + '">' + yyyy + '</option>')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [.add() method](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbojfbj.php)

1. get reference to `<select>` tag | `.querySelector(selector);`
2. create an `<option>` tag | `.createElement("option");`
3. add text | `option.text` property
4. set value | `option.value` property
5. then add `<option>` to `<select>` | `select.add(option)` method
6. repeat process through a `for` loop

---

### Demo

```js
function setOpt(selector, text, value) {
  var node = document.querySelector(selector);
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.text = text;
  opt.value = value;
  node.add(opt);
  return false;
}

function T(t) {
  var now = new Date();
  var time;
  switch (t.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'm':
      time = now.getMonth() + 1;
      break;
    case 'd':
      time = now.getDate();
      break;
    case 'y':
      time = now.getFullYear();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return time;
}
for (let i = 2015; i <= T('y'); i++) {
  setOpt('#cboYear', i, i);
}
```

```html
<div class="cell colspan3">
  <div class="input-control select full-size">
    <h5>Year:</h5>
    <select id="cboYear">
      <option value="0" selected disabled hidden>Select Year</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using `jquery` in your web app, I made a little modification in your posted code. Here is the code for appending years `2015` to present using loops in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        Years(); // this will run the function Years() after the DOM (document object model) has been loaded.
    });

    function Years() {
        // get the current date and put in today variable
        var today = new Date(); 
        // get the year and put it in yyyy variable
        yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        // appending from year 2015 up to present in the select tag
        for (var index = 2015; index <= yyyy; index++) {
            $('#cboYear').append('<option value ="' + index + '">' + index + '</option>')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's help you:

HTML

```
<div class="cell colspan3">
    <div class="input-control select full-size">
        <h5>Year:</h5>
        <select id="cboYear"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script code

```
function Years() {
    var today = new Date();
    var  yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var content = '<option value="-1">Select Year</option>';

    for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++, yyyy++) {
         content += '<option value="' + x + '">' + yyyy + '</option>';
    }
     $('#cboYear').append(content);
}
```

Don't forget to add jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```